# Add canvas attributes dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have the canvas tag in my HTML5 document

```
<canvas id="fooBar" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

And I also have an empty anchor tag

```
<a href="" id="spin">Spin</a>
```

and I build my canvas in the head

```
var fooCanvas = document.getElementById("fooBar");
var barContext = fooCanvas.getContext("2d");
```

Is there a way I can add:

```
barContext.fillText("fubar", x,y);
```

Dynamically via clicking on the anchor tag? What I want is to have a variable in my JS which doesn't always hold the same value, and clicking the a tag would update the canvas fillText attribute every time the link is clicked, My idea to overcome this is to use jQuery and have something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").click(function(event){
            // Something here
        });
    });
```

Obviously this would work on every a tag I have in the document so I'll specify that later on but I'm not too sure on the syntax required to append that canvas attribute to my canvas? Any ideas?

Comment: barContext is not an "attribute" you would have to "append to your canvas". Just call the fillText() function and it will be drawn.

Comment: Yep, you're right - was confusing my terminology. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

```
var fooCanvas = document.getElementById("fooBar");
var barContext = fooCanvas.getContext("2d");

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(event){
        barContext.fillText("fubar", x,y);
    });
});
```

Although you might want to use `button` elements instead of `a`, since they're not actually links.